# How can I use caps lock to change language in VIM

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Can I use capslock for changing languages in VIM instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> in case of "keymap=russian-jcukenwin"?

How can I do it?

Maybe something like mapping it in the `$VIMRC` file? How can I map capslock, is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using X, you can remap the capslock key with [Xmodmap](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Intkeyb/x336.html). Add this to a
file to be sourced by [`xmodmap(1)`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xmodmap.1.html):

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = F2
```

You may replace `F2` with another key. Now you may add a mapping to your
`$VIMRC` file. For example,

```
nnoremap <F2> :echo 'it works!'<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well at least according to this SO Q&A titled: [How to map CAPS LOCK key in VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176532/how-to-map-caps-lock-key-in-vim) it doesn't sound like it's possible with the capslock key.

*excerpt*

> <kbd>Capslock</kbd> (and <kbd>Control</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>
>   etc.) is a modifier key, which means that it's used with another
>   normal key to modify the meaning of that key. AFAIK the OS does not
>   pass the modifier keys to the application unless a normal key has also
>   been pressed, e.g. pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> will not be seen by the
>   application, but <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will be.